# UK or Poland better for buying US dollars?

Tags: usa, money, exchange

For buying US dollars with Sterling, are the rates likely to be better in UK (before departure) or in Poland (en route)?

Comment: The answer depends on your bank and their fee structure, but often the answer is "get them from an ATM inside the US".

Comment: If you're in the UK and you're not travelling soon you can get a Supercard, which wipes out bank fees apart from 3% on cash withdrawals, which is by far superior to most UK banks' fees (4.75%+ is fairly standard). In addition, I believe most US shops/hotels take card, which comes without a fee.

Comment: When I looked at ATMs they only allow max 800dollars is that normal

Comment: @Suzanne That's per day

Comment: Welcome to TSE. You need to define "best" in order for this to be answerable— best exchange rate? most convenient? safest from crime? lowest fees? Please be sure to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of our site standards and conventions, then [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/57533) the question to incorporate those details, thanks.

Comment: @Suzanne The physical design of certain ATMs used in the US, combined with their only being stocked with $20 bills, combine to limit a single withdrawal to $800 (40 banknotes at a time). It's possible to find ATMs which dispense larger bills, but they're few and far between.

Comment: If you need more than $800/day, it's probably worth considering what you're actually trying to achieve and whether that much cash is the best way to do it. Expensive transactions in the US are generally not conducted in cash (with some exceptions certainly) and carrying around large amounts of cash incurs a risk of theft or loss.